# how to get the browser start/launch event for IE , Firefox and Chrome browsers in windows os?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, npapi

I want this so that I can to do some stuff in my extension when its get loaded first time for a browser session and  skip in successive extension load until the browser is closed.

Comment: Each browser extension system should tell you that.

Comment: @SLaks : Which event should I handle for that?

Comment: Every browser behaves differently. You haven't explained what you mean when you say "browser session" (some consider all tabs to be the same "session" for plugin purposes, others don't), you haven't said what *type* of extension you're talking about, and you haven't explained why this is desirable.

Comment: @EricLaw In my case all tab should be same "session" and extension is java-script extension. I want this so that I can show a alert message when browser loads my extension first time.

Answer (score 1):

Your plugin loads. You look at the window handle of the containing top-level browser window and you create a mutex or some other cross-process-visible object containing that window handle. When the next instance is created, you check for the mutex and if present, you know the extension was already loaded.

Having said that, because of the subtlety in how the browser loads plugins, it is probably worth you updating your question with details of *why* you only need to run the code in question once.